# Center a circle in a square

Tags: wpf, xaml

Say I have the following controls (that I want to put in a Data Template):

```
<Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Black"/>
<Ellipse Width="15" Height="15" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4"/>
```

I would like the circle to be centered exactly in the middle of the square.

Seems easy, but I am just not figuring how to do it.  Everything I try is off to one side or the other by a bit.

Update:

This is my latest attempt that did not work:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Black"/>
    <Ellipse Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="15"  Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"/>
</Grid>
```

It is the closest I can get.

Comment: I suppose it's because 20-15 gives you 5 and it does not divide by 2. When I try `Ellipse` with the size of 14 or 16 it's centred.

Comment: @dkozl - I am more than willing to change the size of the ellipse, but it did not center for me with 14 or 16.  If you have a way please post it!

Comment: Try the answer below. I would suggest same thing

Comment: You need to get rid of the Column/Row definitions for it to work Vaccano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an even-length and an odd-length shape, they can never be perfectly aligned.  Like a 2-unit line and a 3-unit line, they'll always be slightly off:

```
---
--
```

So could I suggest making them both even-length, or both odd-length?

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Stroke="Black"/>
    <Ellipse Width="16" Height="16" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4"/>
</Grid>
```